# DataTables - invalid JSON message appears when using search bar

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to implement [this](http://phpflow.com/php/datatable-pagination-sorting-and-search-server-side-phpmysql-using-ajax/) using DataTables and while the data is displaying correctly, any time I try to use the search bar, filters, I receive the following error:

**DataTables warning: table id=checkin - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1**

When I click into that link and follow the instructions, this is the json from the response.php:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[["28","708089113","Nicole Foster","","","2016-04-15 14:27:36"],["29","708089113","Larry Quaglia","","","2016-04-15 14:28:38"],["30","708089113","Nicole Foster","Test","test@syr.edu","2016-04-21 09:18:59"]]}
```

I am still very new to JSON and AJAX, but when I check what's outputted with the JSON Lint and JSON Parser links on that page, it says they are valid.

Here is my code:

Reports.php (just showing the script to call DataTables)

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#checkin').DataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "dom": 'lBfrtip',
            "ajax":{
                url :"response.php", // json datasource
                type: "post"  // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
                },
            "buttons":[
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons: [
                            'copy',
                            'excel',
                            'csv',
                            'pdf',
                            'print'
                    ]
                }
            ]
            });   
    });
</script>
```

Response.php

```
<?php
//include connection file 
include_once("../connection.php");

// initilize all variable
$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

$params = $_REQUEST;

//define index of column
$columns = array( 
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'suid', 
    2 => 'staffMember',
    3 => 'studentName',
    4 => 'studentEmail',
    5 => 'checkinDateTime'
);

$where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

// check search value exist
if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
    $where .=" WHERE ";
    $where .=" ( studentName LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $where .=" OR staffMember LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
    $where .=" OR studentEmail LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
    $where .=" OR suid LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
    $where .=" OR checkinDate LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
}

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `checkin` ";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;
//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where;
    $sqlRec .= $where;
}


$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

$queryTot = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($VisitorManagement));


$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch check-in data");

//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   

$json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
        "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
?>
```

Connection.php

```
$hostname_VisitorManagement = "localhost";
$database_VisitorManagement = "visitor-management";
$username_VisitorManagement = "***";
$password_VisitorManagement = "***";
$VisitorManagement = mysqli_connect($hostname_VisitorManagement, $username_VisitorManagement, $password_VisitorManagement, $database_VisitorManagement);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Is there something I'm missing? I have looked around on their forums, but I have not seen a solution to the problem similar to mine with code like mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the option `serverSide` to `false`. If set true, the table queries the ajax source each time you try to filter/sort/change page. If you intend to retrieve all the data first, and then work client-side, the `serverSide` option should be `false`

Update: So I'm guessing the issue is datatables not sending any params when making the ajax call, and the query then builds incorrectly.

Try adding such params to the ajax.data option:

```
"ajax":{
     url :"response.php", // json datasource
     type: "post",  // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
     data: {}//data to send
 },
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I set it to false, it immediately pops up the invalid JSON error, gets rid of all my data that was previously displaying, and just shows a "Loading..." message.

Comment: Check on the dev console, the network tab, what's the repsonse from the server.

Comment: "error to fetch check-in data" which is an error message spawned from line 50 in response.php: `$queryRecords = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch checkin data");`

Comment: Good, then we know the problem is in that query! I'd  try to `die(var_dump($sqlRec))` before that line and analyze the query to search for any syntax error.

Comment: Okay, so the error is this: `string(48) "SELECT * FROM checkin  ORDER BY      LIMIT  , "` which means at line 45, this code isn't working properly `$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";` So I'm guessing nothing is pulling from $columns or $params though I thought they were clearly defined based on my database columns.

Comment: see my update on the answer. Keep in mind, though, that if you work with datatables client-side, things like ORDER BY would be useless (Datatables would order by itself)

Comment: It seems that adding the `data: {}` to the ajax area did not resolve anything. I'm still seeing an invalid JSON error message. I apologize if I'm misunderstanding DataTables. I'm still very new to PHP, MySQL, and especially AJAX. Honestly, my goal is to have my table pull from the MySQL database and be searchable, filterable, and can let the user sort it on just the front-end. So if there is any unnecessary code in response.php, let me know.

Comment: mmm, if that's the case, you'd be better off with the basic query (no where's, order by's, limit's, etc) and let datatables handle that client-side. Datatables is by default sortable by columns and has a filter field. Try `SELECT * FROM checkin`. Make sure that the result has the same amount of columns that datatables (datatables should have defined its columns in the configuration and HTML, check here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns)

Comment: I'm sorry if I come off as a newbie. Should I be creating the basic query in response.php or just not use it anymore? Should I be removing parameters in the reports.php script? I tried various ways of barebones stripping both reports and response by going back to how to [DataTable's example](http://phpflow.com/php/datatable-pagination-sorting-and-search-server-side-phpmysql-using-ajax/), but I received the invalid JSON error again.

Comment: hey is alright! Sorry if I'm not being clear, english isn't my native language anyway. What I meant by "basic query" is just the select, with no filtering or ordering options, Datables filter/sorting features can deal with that client-side. the $params array is the one causing trouble: the server isn't receiving anything, so is pretty much empty, and the query being built was incorrect, so if you just make "SELECT * FROM checking", the query should work and return some data. Afterwards, you should check if datatables has its columns defined. Keep checking for the response in the dev console!

Comment: After some time away from it, I figured out that just commenting out line 44 `$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";` solved the issue. That was the problem area, so I just commented it out and it seems to work. Thank you for your help.